# How to match URLs with python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, url

My problem is, that I want to match URLs in HTML code, which look like so: `href='example.com'` or using `"`, but I only want to extract the actual URL. I tried matching it, and then using array magic to only get the array, but since the regex match is *greedy*, if there is more than 1 rational match, there will be lots more which start at one `'` and end at another URL's `'`. What regex will suit my needs?

Comment: So you want regex that will check for `href=` first, and what address is after is what do you want? Any needs for http, checking for www or anything like that?

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python regex URL", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  After that, we should see the code you're using and the *specific* problem you have.
[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: @Shan any URL should be matched, so a (asterisk)(dot)(asterisk) - formatting is what I want to use

Comment: I think you will get a kick out of the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @DaniFoldi so... you just anwsered your own question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend ***NOT*** using regex to parse HTML. Your life will be much easier if you use something like `beautifulsoup`!

It's as easy as this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

HTML = """<a href="https://firstwebsite.com">firstone</a><a href="https://secondwebsite.com">Ihaveurls</a>"""

s = BeautifulSoup(HTML)

for href in s.find_all('a', href=True): print("My URL: ", href['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks, it really did the job!

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want it to solve it using regular expression instead of using other libraries of python. Here is the solution.

```
import re
html = '<a href="https://www.abcde.com"></a>'
pattern = r'href=\"(.*)\"|href=\'(.*)\''
multiple_match_links = re.findall(pattern,html)
if(len(multiple_match_links) == 0):
     print("No Link Found")
else:
     print([x for x in list(multiple_match_links[0]) if len(x) > 0][0])
```

Comment: Thanks, it is interesting to see that it is possible in just a few lines without libraries.